# how to start all daemon process in hadoop - like start-all.sh in linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, hadoop

i have just started to work on hadoop, cygwin in windows 7. i need to know , that is there any method to start all the services using command like- start-all.sh in linux. i used this command in cygwin doesnt work. And if possible pls suggest me any reference to work on hadoop in windows 7 with cygwin.

i need to do following steps every time to start five daemons like

```
Start the namenode in the first window by executing
cd hadoop
bin/hadoop namenode

Start the secondary namenode in the second window by executing
cd hadoop
bin/hadoop secondarynamenode

Start the job tracker the third window by executing
cd hadoop
bin/haoop jobtracker

Start the data node the fourth window by executing
cd hadoop
bin/haoop datanode

Start the task tracker the fifth window by executing
cd hadoop
bin/haoop tasktracker
```

pls any body help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `for` condition to match the path of your Hadoop daemons:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-* /etc/init.d/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-*
 do
   sudo $service start
 done
```

Comment: hi, i am using windows 7 , i cannot use sudo in this.